# Diagnosing K3S Ingress 404

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, k3s, traefik-ingress

I am unable to get even the most basic examples of Ingress Resources working in K3S.

According to the documentation, a Traefik Ingress Controller is installed by default but it doesn't seem to handle/see any Ingress Resources I create. The response is always 404 or 500. It does however respond with the correct TLS certificate configured in my Ingress Resource definition (secretName: tls-secret).

- How can I view traefik logs?

  - And increase verbosity?
- No IngressClass exists in the cluster. Is this a problem?
- How are Ingress Resources linked/assigned an Ingress Controller?
- Any general diagnosis tips would be appreciated

I can see a `traefik` deployment and shell into a pod which has a `traefik` binary but I can see no traefik configuration in `/etc` nor any logs in `/var/logs`.

### Service

The following service is exposed and accessible via NodePort on `https://myhost.com:30005/v2/_catalog`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: registry-docker-registry
  namespace: registry
  labels:
    app: docker-registry
    chart: docker-registry-2.0.0
    release: registry
    heritage: Helm
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      name: https-5000
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30005
  selector:
    app: docker-registry
    release: registry
```

### Ingress

Here is my Ingress Resource.

- I don't see how this resource is "linked" to any controller
- I don't see how this resource specifies HTTPS anywhere
- The ingress (in K9S) shows ports 80 and 443 - I only want HTPPS 443

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: registry
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myhost.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: registry-docker-registry
              port:
                number: 5000
```

UPDATE:
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412376/internal-server-error-with-traefik-https-backend-on-port-443) the issue could be that traefik does not trust the certificate installed on my application (pod). Indeed it is a corporate CA signed certificate so I would have to tell traefik about the CA Root somehow.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was Traefik not trusting the signer of the backend TLS certificate.

Thanks to [this](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1313#issuecomment-918113786) thread the solution was to `kubectl apply` this configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: helm.cattle.io/v1
kind: HelmChartConfig
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  valuesContent: |-
    globalArguments:
    - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"
    logs:
      access:
        enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Ingress resource must be in the same namespace as of the service object.

Comment: Yes, they were. The controller doesn't have to be though. I'll update my question.